# Error en Xamarin Forms <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: c#, xamarin

Me podrian ayudar con este error de excepcion en xamarin, no puedo encontrar el error, estoy realizando un  MasterDetailPage, las demas paginas funcionan invividualmente incluyendo la del menu

[image: error]

aqui es donde me marca el error

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MasterPage));
        Navigator = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage>(this, "Navigator");
    }
```

este es mi codigo en xaml

```
    *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages;assembly=ProyectoAnimalCared"
             x:Class="ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages.MasterPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MenuPage></pages:MenuPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator"
                    BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainColor}">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainPage>
                </pages:MainPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>*


    namespace ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages
{

    public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            App.Master = this;
            App.Navigator = this.Navigator;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40983113/4092887) o busca `xamarin.forms.xaml.xamlparseexception timeout exceeded getting exception details` en Google. Si encuentras la respuesta, no olvides [publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario ya lo pude resolver, lo hice de nuevo

Comment: Daniel, puedes [publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Lee aquí [cómo elaborar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - le será de mucha ayuda a la comunidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error era que había elegido el elemento `Master Detail Page` lo cual solo lo cambié por `Content Page`.

---

Para poder solucionar este problema, solo volví a crear de nuevo una página seleccione la opcion de content page:

*Creación de la página Content Page:*

[image: error]

Después incluí el siguiente código a la página:

En `xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages;assembly=ProyectoAnimalCared" x:Class="ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages.MasterPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MenuPage></pages:MenuPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator" BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainColor}">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainPage></pages:MainPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

En el `xaml.cs` incluí el siguiente código:

```
namespace ProyectoAnimalCared.Pages
{

    public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            App.Master = this;
            App.Navigator = this.Navigator;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (resultado.Count() > 0)
                {
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
                }
                else
                {
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginInicio());
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw; //// aqui me sale el mensaje me pueden ayudar
            }
        }
```

Comment: estas preguntando o respondiendo a la duda?

Comment: respondiendo amigo, ya habia encontrado mi error